# ProxyPassReverse doesn't keep me on the proxy URL when I click around

Tags: apache2, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have the following virtual host on my personal web server which runs on my NAS.I have dynDNS setup to redirect both mydomain.com and *.mydomain.com to my NAS.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName redir.example.com
    ProxyPass /pbay/ http://www.anothersite.example.com/
    ProxyPassReverse /pbay/ http://www.anothersite.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

when I try to visit `redir.example.com/pbay/`,it is redirecting to `www.anothersite.example.com/` and the address bar still shows `redir.example.com/pbay/` as intended. But when I do anything on the site which results in another request to the server, the address bar is changing to real (anothersite.example.com) address. I want to always show only `http://redir.example.com/`.

I thought that is what ProxyPassReverse is for. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I wonder what pbay could be

Answer (score 1):

You would also need to enable [mod_proxy_html](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_html.html).  `ProxyPassReverse` only rewrites the HTTP headers.  To rewrite the content of the HTML (such as absolute links), you need to enable the additional module.

[The documentation for ProxyPassReverse](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) states this pretty clearly:

> This directive lets Apache httpd adjust the URL in the `Location`,
>   `Content-Location` and `URI` headers on HTTP redirect responses. This is
>   essential when Apache httpd is used as a reverse proxy (or gateway) to
>   avoid by-passing the reverse proxy because of HTTP redirects on the
>   backend servers which stay behind the reverse proxy.
>
> Only the HTTP response headers specifically mentioned above will be
>   rewritten. Apache httpd will not rewrite other response headers, nor
>   will it by default rewrite URL references inside HTML pages. This
>   means that if the proxied content contains absolute URL references,
>   they will by-pass the proxy. To rewrite HTML content to match the
>   proxy, you must load and enable [mod_proxy_html](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_html.html).